# lmfit ODE fitting error: different shape between residuals and data

Tags: python, numpy, ode, lmfit

So I am trying to fit some electrochemical data into a Michaelis Menten model (ODE) with python and the library lmfit. I put the code of the fitting below, which comes from an example at [Text](https://people.duke.edu/%7Eccc14/sta-663/CalibratingODEs.html):

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
from scipy.integrate import odeint
df = pd.read_csv("example3.csv", header=None, nrows=300) 
data=df[2].values
t = time_x

def f(xs, t, ps):
    R=1
    try:
        alpha = ps['alpha'].value
        Vmax = ps['Vmax'].value
        Km=ps['Km'].value
    except:
        alpha, Vmax, Km = ps
    S = xs
    dsdt=R-alpha*(Vmax*S/(Km+S))
    return dsdt

def g(t, x0, ps):

    solution = odeint(f, x0, t, args=(ps,))
    return solution

def residual(ps, ts, data):
    x0 = ps['x0'].value
    model = g(ts, x0, ps)
    return (model - data).ravel()



# set parameters incluing bounds
parameters = Parameters()
parameters.add('x0', value=float(data[0]), min=0, max=100)
parameters.add('Vmax',value=18,min=0, max=100)
parameters.add('alpha',value=1,min=0, max=1)
parameters.add('Km',value=5,min=0,max=100)

# fit model and find predicted values
result = minimize(residual, parameters, args=(t, data), method='leastsq')
final = data + result.residual.reshape(data.shape)

# plot data and fitted curves
plt.plot(t, data, 'o')
plt.plot(t, final, '--', linewidth=2, c='blue');

# display fitted statistics
report_fit(result)
```

And I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-1bd65276a496> in <module>
     38 # fit model and find predicted values
     39 result = minimize(residual, parameters, args=(t, data), method='leastsq')
---> 40 final = data + result.residual.reshape(data.shape)
     41 
     42 # plot data and fitted curves

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 90000 into shape (300,)
```

I know what it means, residual array is of larger size that data and it cannot reshape it. But technically residuals should be the same size as data. If someone is familiar with the lmfit library it would be a massive help. I hope it is a dumb question, I just cannot see the error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are having a problem with the broadcast of arrays, the result of `odeint` is a column vector, the data treated as row, the difference is broadcast as matrix having `300*300=90000` elements.

Reduce the shape of the `odeint` result at some place, for instance in

```
return solution[:,0]
```

Comment: Yes! that fully solved it! I did not know odeint returns a column vector. Thank you very much!

Comment: It returns a list of state vectors, in contrast to solve_ivp, where the returned array is transposed to that.